# My baby guppie is having trouble swimming

Tags: fish

I just got home and my baby guppie is at the bottom of my 10gallon tank, and he seems to be having troubles to swim... i don't know what to do please help:(
( points that may help:
 He is as big as a neon tetra
 It's only him and a neon tetra in the tank- yes I know I need more of each kind but I haven't had time to get more at this point)

Comment: have you taken a water test and what does it show.a guppy the size of a neon tetra is not a baby anymore.

Comment: As trond says, do a water test. If you can, upload a picture for us to look at too.

Comment: I got given a tank with some products in it; including a  ph up, multi medication for common disease, ph tester card, instructions and a ph tester product but they are from different brands.. don't know if that's ok? But it's all I had right now.. I will get a new set soon.. but that's all I really have for now...

Comment: This is gonna sound stupid but if the waters at 6.6ph then would you use ph up or down?

Comment: you need to use the ph up(ph up is an alcaline solution and ph down is an acidic solution)but there is better natural ways to addjust the ph in a fish tank and less costly too both for the health of your fish and your wallet.

Comment: What are the other ways?